# How do I add an listener to combobox java

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, listener

I am trying to add a listener to my combobox on javafx.
Here is the code for my combobox:

```
ObservableList<String> options =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Option1",
                "Option2",
                "Option3",
                "Option4"
        );

final ComboBox comboBox;

public ComboBox getComboBox() {
    return comboBox;
}

public ComboBoxStatus() {
    this.comboBox = new ComboBox(options);
    comboBox.setValue("option1");
}
```

and I want to add something like:
whenever something has been changed like option1 to option2 call a function and do sth

As seen above I have added the default value to `option1`. So I want to call a function when I change the current value, which is `option1` as the default value, to e.g. `option2`.

On my Main programm I have while loop and I would like to read the current selected value from my combobox.

How do I read the current selected value?

Comment: You can listen to the value change: `comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { doSomething();  });`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
        fComboBoxDefault.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object arg1,
                    Object arg2) {

                    // Do Something ...

                }
            }    
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer ! Can u tell me what are the difference between this solution and the one from DVarge (see comment above)

Comment: They are the same actually.